# Running Cucumber Tests with Selenium on Mac OSX 10.11 For Safari

Tags: macos, selenium, cucumber, behat, safaridriver

I've been searching around for a way to run our Behat (PHP dist of Cucumber) tests on Safari, however we encounter the problem of Selenium Safari Driver not being able to use simple click functionality, which is breaking the majority of our browser tests.

As Safari (at time of writing this post) is around 9% of all browser usage, according to [browser stats](http://gs.statcounter.com/#desktop+tablet-browser-ww-monthly-201501-201603), it is a necessity to test it.

The click functionality works with Chrome, Firefox and Opera.

Does anyone have any solutions?

- Mac OSX 10.11
- Safari 9.0
- Selenium Safari Driver 2.47.1
- Latest SafariDriver.safariextz
- Behat 2.5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as there is still an [open issue](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1185) concerning the Selenium Safari Driver with Safari 9. You could try to apply the suggestion in [one of the comments](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1185#issuecomment-159486162).

Comment: As there are no other answers, this will be the one I accept and award bounty to, as it explains why there is a problem, however I may re-open this question if there is still a problem after the issue is resolved.